# Schengen Visa rules

Tags: integer-partitions

If a tourist wants to visit europe with a schengen visa, the following rules apply:

1. maximum contiguous stay is 90 days (in the following treated as 3
   months)
2. in any 180 day interval the sum of days must not exceed 90
   days.

If somebody wants to visit europe as much as possible, the following visit pattern is possible:
3mi-3mo - 3mi-3mo... which means: 3 month in the schengen area, 3 months out and same again. This is xxx---

Also all these monthly patterns work for repeated visits (x=1 month in schengen area, - =1 month not in schengen):

```
xx-x--
xx--x-
xx---x
x-xx--
x--xx-
x-x-x-
```

Are all visit pattern allowed with 3 months in schengen and 3 months outside?

Now, what are the rules for combining patterns?
For example it is obvious that a pattern like "xx---x" cannot be followed by "xxx---".

Comment: What is the definition of "a pattern"?

Comment: The first rule is redundant.